# building string from big list of words

Tags: python, search, design-patterns

I don't know the type of this algmaybe it's famous..

I have a liste of this form

```
L = [ ["a"] , ["b"] , ["c"] ] , [ ["d"] , ["e"] , ["f"] ] , ["g"], ["h"], ["i"] ] ,[ ["j"] , ["k"] , ["l"] ]
```

where the letter are words and the length of L could be from 2 to 50 elements but inside the list are always 3 elements long.

And I want to create a list who build all this string :

```
"adgj"
"adgk"
"adgl"
"adhj"
"adhk"
"adhl"
"adij"
"adik"
"adil"
"aegj"
```

ect all the way to `"cfil"`

could someone tell me what to do or where to look for?

Thank's a lot for your help..

Comment: this `L` of yours is not a valid Python object. The brackets are not balanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use any other module and do all the work yourself, following code will give you the result,

```
L = [[ ["a"] , ["b"] , ["c"] ] , [ ["d"] , ["e"] , ["f"] ] , [["g"], ["h"], ["i"] ] ,[ ["j"] , ["k"] , ["l"] ]]
words = []

def a(string):
  i = len(string)
  if(i==len(L)):
    words.append(string)
  else:
    for element in L[i]:
      a(string+element[0])

a('')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `itertools.product` to achieve this efficiently:

```
import itertools

L = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']], [['d'], ['e'], ['f']], [['g'], ['h'], ['i']], [['j'], ['k'], ['l']]

for item in itertools.product(*L):
    ''.join([str(x) for y in item for x in y])
```

Comment: I am curious as to the possibilites of using [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) in this case. How do you think it could be achieveable, if doable ?

Comment: The `combinations` methods are usually used for combinations *within* a single list, rather than across lists - hence why product is a better fit here. It might be doable, but I can't off the top of my head think of an easy route.

Comment: I'm getting a `ImportError: No module named product` error. Also, is `str(x)` really needed? You are dealing with strings anyway.

Comment: Also, if you want to make it less readable, but shorter, you can replace the list comprehension with `chain.from_iterable` ;-) `''.join(chain.from_iterable(item))`

Comment: @MaciejGol - fixed the import line - thanks. the `str` might not be needed here, but it's good practice since `join` will die if it ever isn't a string.